# Proving $(A \lor ¬B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$ is a tautology with Fitch-style deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

In [forall x: Calgary, by P. D. Magnus](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf), chapter 16, appears this exercise:

[image]

I do not know how to derive a contradiction in line 4. I came up with this basic skeleton. How can I continue the proof ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, because this statement is not valid!

Consider: $A$ is True and $B$ is False. Then the whole statement evaluates to:

$$(T \lor \neg F) \to (T \to F) = (T \lor T) \to F = T \to F = F$$

So (assuming the proof system is sound), this statement is just not provable.

Are you sure the statement is not $(\neg A \lor B) \to (A \to B)$?  Because that one is valid, and so (assuming the proof system is complete) you should be able to prove that one.

BTW: If the statement *were* provable, your skeleton is good! Good job

Comment: It's the first exercise on page 154, number 5. Thank you ! You are right. I spent 3 hours on it thinking there must be a way to prove it...

Comment: @F.Zer Maybe that was the point of the exercise .... :)

Comment: It said: "Use strategies to find proofs for each of the following sentences". I was sure they were asking for a proof. It was good practice, anyway :-)

Comment: @F.Zer Just found the online book. It's open source so I added the link in your post. And you're right: the exercise assume it is provable ... oopsie!